# creating an entire database from a sql script

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL script `myDatabase.sql` of a database I created. How would I run this script in SQL Server Management Studio to create my database there? Can I just open it and run it in the program or do I have to do anything first?

Comment: It should work provided you have the correct rights.  I would probably do the 'create database' bit first and run the rest of the creates later.

Comment: Depends on whether this script also creates the **database** itself - if not, you might need to create one before running this script (so your database objects like tables etc. will be created in the right database for you to use later on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes that would work. Or you can open it with a text editor and copy paste the content in your DBMS and run it!